# How can one bound a selection of items (as below) using a pair of vertical parallel lines?

Tags: graphics, mdframed

The following represents the elements of a theorem which I want to highlight from start to finish between a pair of vertical parallel lines.

1. A block of text.
2. An equation - not necessarily numbered.
3. A graphic from an eps file at scale 1.00
4. Some more text.

It appears that tcolorbox and tikz - being drawing tools - are not appropriate for such a requirement, whereas mdframed would be ideal; but it is not often mentioned.

This would seem to apply to a number of applications.
Could someone direct me to the correct syntax, please>

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[draw=DarkBlue, line width=1.0pt, 
                    inner sep=12pt, inner ysep=6pt] 
    \node at (0,0) [rectangle,draw,fill=LightBlue]{% 
        \begin{minipage}[t]{118mm}% Items 1, 2, 3, 4 as in my original question. I want only the left and right lines to appear. Tried adapting the line commented-out below, but cannot control placement.
          \vspace{2pt}% 
          \draw [line width=0.25mm, red ] (0,-1) -- (2,-1) node [right] {\SI{0.25}{\milli\meter}};; 
        \end{minipage}}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed a visual example, even done with external software, to show what you want to achieve.

Comment: \begin{tikzpicture}[draw=DarkBlue,line width=1.0pt,inner sep=12pt,inner ysep=6pt]
\node at (0,0) [rectangle,draw,fill=LightBlue]{ % 
\begin{minipage}[t]{118mm} %

Items 1, 2, 3, 4 as in my original question.

I want only the left and right lines to appear.

Tried adapting the line commented-out below, but cannot control placement.\vspace{2pt}
% \draw [line width=0.25mm, red ] (0,-1) -- (2,-1) node [right] {\SI{0.25}{\milli\meter}};;
\end{minipage}};
\end{tikzpicture}

Comment: Do you mean a line on the left margin and the other line on the right margin? Should it be one pair for each element.? Or for the whole theorem?

Comment: As bounded by a rectangle of width, say 100mm, but with the top and bottom boundaries open.  It does not matter about page breaks.

Comment: `mdframed` does indeed have the ability to do what you want, and the manual contains the necessary information to generate that configuration.  (i've done something similar but more complex; it's too much different to just copy the code.)  but i've come around to thinking that `tcolorbox` would probably have been easier and perhaps more manageable, so i suggest you take a look at that too, as proposed in the answer by ignasi.

Comment: Ignasi and Barbara beeton - many thanks for you efforts, again.  Having tried the tcolorbox solution below, I now realize that the structure of my document is compromised (a little) because the figure numbering is missing.  Is it not possible to draw a rectangle and color only the vertical edges,  i.e. effectively color individual edges?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why `tcolorbox` is not suited for that so I propose a solution with this package. It includes a captioned figure with `caption` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{%
breakable,
notitle,
colback=blue!10!white,
colframe=blue!60!black,
sharp corners,
boxsep=0pt,
left=12pt, right=12pt,
top=6pt, bottom=6pt,
boxrule=0pt,leftrule=1pt,rightrule=1pt,
#1
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{mybox}

Some previous text: \lipsum[2]

An unnumbered equation:
\[\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1 \]

A numbered equation:
\begin{equation}
\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1 
\end{equation}

A figure with caption:
{\par\centering
 \includegraphics[width=.75\textwidth]{example-image}
 \captionof{figure}{This is a figure inside a \texttt{tcolorbox}}
 \par}

Some more text: \lipsum[4]
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ignasi - you said previously that because a figure is a "floating object" - not just a graphic - tcolorbox could not give a complete solution, whereas mdframed could.  That is why I posed the new question.

Comment: @keith77777 A "floating object" and a "figure with caption" are different things. The second one is possible with `tcolorbox` with `caption` package help as is shown in my updated example. By the way, `mdframed` detects if it used inside a `float` or not which is also different from declaring a float inside a framed environment.

Comment: \begin{mybox}
\begin{tcolorbox}
[width=106.4mm,colframe=DarkRed,colback=LightCream,top=2pt,bottom=2pt,left=2.2pt,right=2.2pt,arc=2pt,boxrule=1.0pt] % left=2.8pt, right=2.4pt
\centering
{\par\centering
 \includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{example-image}
 \captionof{subfigure}{This is a figure inside a \texttt{tcolorbox}}
 \par}
{\par\centering
 \includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{example-image}
 \captionof{subfigure}{This is a second figure inside a \texttt{tcolorbox}}
 \par}
\end{tcolorbox}
\captionof{figure}{Main caption for two sub-figs}
\end{mybox}

Comment: I have imitated your syntax to include sub figs, and it appears to work.  One last point: what is it that controls the vertical positioning of the sub captions, please?  Thanks again.

Comment: @keith77777 According to page 13 in `caption` documentation, it seems that `skip` option determines distance between figure and caption.

Comment: Ignasi - problem; each time I use this construction, all the text that follows the construction throughout the document changes to color red - including the headers.  \color{black} corrects matters, but is that a fudge?

Comment: @keith77777 Which `tcolorbox` version do you use? With last one (3.80) I don't have this problem.

Comment: Ignasi - I update my miktex table of packages every two weeks or so.  However, only yesterday, I altered something and the problem has gone away.  I'm sorry, I have no idea what it was, but I'm happy with your solution.